# How to make HTML footer div stick to the bottom of the page

Tags: html

I'm writing my home page in and the footer is shown on top of the main section.

I tried adding `position:relative` and `position:absolute;bottom:0;` but it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `height` from CSS style in this classes : `.login` and `.homeArticle` that way it will always fit at the bottom.